# Is there a way to remove 2 letters from a cell with a string (if they exist), and add a symbol on the end of the string?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to code a google sheet to help develop a system to keep track of what training different people have. This is for an online role-playing game, to keep track of what spells/abilities different people have learnt. We've assigned different trainings a letter in the alphabet for ease of use. When someone has multiple trainings under a certain category, I want these to be able to combine to give a symbol rather than a letter. For example, if "A" and "T" are both related, I want them to be able to combine to give the "#" symbol.

It's a strange concept, I know, but this is the way our system has been built. I want to be able to have all people in the tracker sheet, then on a separate sheet, I want to be able to type their name in, and it will spit out their compressed training history.
The sheet's columns are formatted like so:

```
1. |  A  |    B     | C | D | E | F |... (Column)
2. |Name | Position | A | B | C | D |... (Header)
3. |John |  Wizard  | T | F | T | T |... (Data)
```

I've set up the main sheet, so that when I type their name, it uses the formula:

```
=JOIN("",
    ARRAYFORMULA(
        IF(
            INDEX(Tracker!C:AB,MATCH(A2,Tracker!A:A,0),Tracker!C:AB),Tracker!C1:AB1,
)))
```

I've tried using regex extract/replace, however I'm not too good with regex, and I only want to replace characters with a symbol if BOTH exist, otherwise just leave it.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cYGgmFJGGMtmwy6LF5k91H3-6UBVYIH_n8TIn1TU1Cw/edit?usp=sharing

Up there is a link to a sheet I just made, showing what I want to do. If anyone has suggestions, or questions, feel free to leave them here, or comment it on the spreadsheet.

Thank you in advance for any responses.

Answer (score 0):

You may try below formula-

```
=REGEXREPLACE(JOIN("",FILTER(Tracker!C1:AB1,INDEX(Tracker!C2:AB,MATCH(A2,Tracker!A2:A,0)))),"[AT]","")&"#"
```

- Here `INDEX()/MATCH()` will detect and return row based on name.
- `FILTER()` will return characters based on selection of checkboxes of person row.
- `JOIN()` will concat all characters in a single string.
- Finally `REGEXREPLACE(#,"[AT]","")` will remove `A` & `T`.

[image]